# Connection refused error post request from PHP to node.js

Tags: php, node.js

I'm running scotch box (a vagrant LAMP stack which runs in a Ubuntu VM)

I'm running node.js on Windows.

Here's my node.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var mysql = require('mysql');

http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on port *:3000');
});

app.post('/phpreq', function (req, res) {
var content = req.body;
console.log(content);
res.end('ok');
})
```

Here's my PHP code:

```
$data = array("request" => "disconnect", "userid" => "5");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('http://localhost:3000/phpreq');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

echo curl_exec($ch)."\n";
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    die('Couldn\'t send request: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
```

The error I receive is: Couldn't send request: Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused

I've tried disabling my firewall and allowing port 3000 through my firewall as well.

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: can you try to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost? may be it's a problem.. I've met this kind of issue while using localhost in mysql connection string.

Comment: Same error: Couldn't send request: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 3000: Connection refused

Comment: oh.. I've been distracted :) .. you're using VM.. as answer below says, you need to forward your local port to vm-port, or use vm ip directly.. I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. I solved it by listening on 0.0.0.0 in node.js and using 192.168.33.10 (vagrant's IP in PHP for the cURL post request).

My new node.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var mysql = require('mysql');

http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on port *:3000');
});

app.post('/phpreq', function (req, res) {
var content = req.body;
console.log(content);
res.end('ok');
})
```

New PHP code:

```
$data = array("request" => "disconnect", "userid" => "5");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('http://192.168.33.1:3000/phpreq');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

echo curl_exec($ch)."\n";
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    die('Couldn\'t send request: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that port 3000 that you connect to is on the correct host.

You may need to use the gateway address (run `netstat -rn` on the guest OS to see what it is), use your local IP address other than localhost so that the correct interface is used, or use some form of port forwarding (from guest 3000 to host 3000).

When you use localhost (or 127.0.0.1, it's the same) in a vagrant box then you access a port on that box, not on a host machine.

There are several ways that networking can be configured in Vagrant so you need to read the docs and see how it is in your case.

See:

- https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/networking.html
- https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm trying port forwarding to make it work. I tried adding this line: `config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000` and then I used vagrant reload. But it still gives me the same error: Couldn't send request: Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused